# Кодировка в режиме сборки Release

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

В проекте использую только Use Multi-Byte Character Set, то есть ASCII. В режиме сборки Debug все работает хорошо. Но, переключаясь на Release, возникает много ошибок, связанных с конвертацией char - > wchar_t. В настройках стоит ASCII и весь код под ASCII, но сборщик для Release собирает все как Unicode. Кто виноват ?

Кодировка проекта уставливается в Properties -> General -> Projects Defaults, что вроде для всех сборок.

Тип проекта Visual C++ Win32 Console Application.

Answer (score 0):

`Projects Defaults` это параметры проекта в текущей конфигурации, что можно выбрать вверху окна. Там у Вас стоит `Debug`, а нужно выбрать `Release` и установить для него подобающие параметры, либо же выбрать `All Configurations` и назначить общие для всех типов сборки параметры.